# Setting up a GCP Service Account to use Google Play Store Dev API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-play-console, service-accounts

I need to create a backend logic to use [Google Play Developer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate).

This API does not support API Keys but should use [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) for calls.

What I did:

1. Created a new service account
2. Added Owner permissions (for testing purposes)
3. Generated the key
4. In the Play console, I configured the API Access (https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers//api-access) - added Admin permissions for the app and account

Running the code leads to error 401.

I am not sharing the test code, because in the same GCP project I see another service account configured some time ago, and my test backend code works well with the associated key. But not with the newly created one.

I compared all permissions between these two accounts, but it is still 401. I can assume it is related to the service account configuration itself because it is 401 (having issues with API Access might give 403). Both accounts are enabled.

Any ideas about what other differences can be to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend following this blog post which shows how to set up a Google Cloud service account with the Google Play Developer API including linking a Google Cloud project.

https://www.devdigital.com/techhub/detail/google-play-developer-api-how-to-create-a-service-account-

Comment: this does not help. I have an old service account on the same project that works. I created exactly the same account as it is mentioned in the article, and the same code does not work with the generated key

Comment: at the end the main issue is that it takes 1+ days to propagate changes that's why it did not work

Answer (score 0):

For readers from 2024+: the flow to authorize Service Account to Google Play Developer API has been changed. There is no section `Settings/ API Access` now in Google Play mentioned in the link posted in Holt's answer above.

In my case I solved 403 errors by inviting Service Account's email (you can get it from `Service accounts` section [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)) to Google Play Console on [Users & Permissions page](https://play.google.com/console/users-and-permissions).

Follow this guide https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started

You will also need to select a proper permissions for this service account email.